# C# escape curly bracket not working with format modifier?

Tags: c#

I know we can escape curly bracket in C# using `{{` and `}}`. But they don't seem to work well if they are right after a format modifier (like `{0:F6}`).

```
string str;

// Prints "{3.14}" as expected
str = string.Format("{{{0}}}", 3.14);
Console.WriteLine(str);

// Expected "{3.140000}", found "{F6}"
str = string.Format("{{{0:F6}}}", 3.14);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Why don't you just `str = "{" + string.Format("{0:F6}", 3.14) + "}";`

Comment: @Pikoh i think the question is more about "is this intended behaviour in c#"

Comment: @blas3nik's answer explains why; see also MSDN "Escaping Braces" in "[Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)" where it is clearly explained; specifically "*interpreting nested braces is not supported*".

Comment: pi =~ 3.14159265... so you would want 3.141593

Comment: kludge `str = "{" + string.Format("{0:F6}", 3.14) + "}";` 
`Console.WriteLine(str);`

Comment: @user1666620 there are only 3 instances of {{ in the c# 5.0 language specification, so it's not an intended behaviour of c# ~~ twice in `7.6.10.4 array creation expressions` and once in `12.6 array initializers`; it's a design consideration of the .NET Framework found in "[.NET Framework Application Essentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172157(v=vs.110).aspx)" under "[Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how C# processes curly brackets, it's well known.
[See here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/01/14/58851.aspx)

You can escape it like this (for example, there are different ways):

```
 var str = string.Format("{0}{1:F6}{2}", "{", 3.14, "}");
 Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: thanks for the link - something to remember if I ever come across this. I'd upvote this twice if I could.

Comment: Your answer is correct (+1) but I'd definitely call this a bug that Microsoft simply never fixed.

Comment: @xxbbcc its not a bug. `F6}}` is taken as format of variable. btw it would be nice if they make it non-greedy ;)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yes, I read the linked article and I meant that the greediness of the implementation is the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 String.Format("{0}{1:F6}{2}", "{",3.14, "}")
```